# Download file via button

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

On my webpage I have a button.
When I click on it, I want it to send a document to the browser.

Here is the code in the click event:

```
Private Sub btMNCgetTemplate_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btMNCgetTemplate.Click
    Dim MNCid As Integer = Me.cbMNCrequestType.SelectedValue
    Dim mncRT As New MinorNetworkChangeTypeOfRequests
    Dim MNCrq As New MNCTypeOfRequestItem

    MNCrq = mncRT.Find(MNCid)
    If MNCrq IsNot Nothing Then
        If MNCrq.Form.ToLower.EndsWith(".doc") Or 
           MNCrq.Form.ToLower.EndsWith(".docx") Then
            Response.ContentType = "Application/msword"
        Else
            Response.ContentType = "Application/x-msexcel"
        End If

        Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", MNCrq.Form))
        Response.TransmitFile(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/forms/{0}", MNCrq.Form)))
        Response.End()
    End If
End Sub
```

The MNCrq object Form property has the name of the file.

In the beginning this worked fine, the user got a save file window.
But now it is not working anymore.
When I run the website in Chrome, nothing happens.
When I run the website in IE9, I get the following error message in some file that isn't mine:

```
Unhandled exception at line 940, column 13 in http://localhost:29226/ScriptResource.axd?
d=DbqlGCg_y1TWNdNykQXSWTqf7VMHZvfOOc8W9SvKy5VJEvrKhkNOK5JNcaIC4d76X42JcWSxljh5epK1GqlRC4_NnfoLlKD1PfZ2-dNg98DHOKlBmICo8PKGlg73PqEQJR5AdM_sf6udu_6Vkp3cg9MicDI1&t=7c776dc1

0x800a139e - Microsoft JScript runtime error: Sys.WebForms.PageRequestManagerParserErrorException: The message received from the server could not be parsed.
```

What am I doing wrong here?

rg,
Eric

Comment: FYI: Your docx MIME type is not correct. It should be `application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `WriteFile`. Please make sure `Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/forms/{0}", MNCrq.Form))` return valid file that exists.

```
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", 
   String.Format("attachment; filename={0}", MNCrq.Form))
Response.WriteFile(Server.MapPath(String.Format("~/forms/{0}", MNCrq.Form)))
Response.End();
```

Comment: Look like you have script error from one of server controls. Please make sure you are not downloading file via Ajax or UpdatePanel. And comment out server controls one at a time and narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I'm barely a professional, but I'm going to try and suggest something I did myself once :)

Why don't you add the file into the directory of your website, and use, as a random example,

```
Server.Transfer("C:\Users\Eric\Desktop\Website\Attachments\WordFile.docx")
```

or change the button to a hyperlink and link it to the file? It's a way of making things simpler, it requires less code and it's less prone to errors.

Answer (score 0):

Used another solution.

I created a new ASPX page and put in the load event the following code:

```
 Dim bestand As String = Page.Request("file")

Response.ClearContent()
Response.ClearHeaders()
Dim fi As New FileInfo(Server.MapPath(".\forms\") + bestand)

Response.ContentType = "application/x-unknown" ' arbitrary 
Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=" + bestand)
Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", fi.Length.ToString())

Response.BinaryWrite(File.ReadAllBytes(fi.FullName))

Response.End()
```

from my button event I call it by:

```
 Response.Redirect(String.Format("givefile.aspx?file={0}", MNCrq.Form), False)
```

Now I get the file.

rg.
Eric

Comment: It is not a good practice using aspx as a file handler (although it works). If you want to serve file, I would like to suggest ashx.